# Perform transition effects on display:none element with hack

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to smoothly display `div` from `display:none` to `display:block`. I know it can't be done to `display:none`, so I tried firstly to apply `display:block` and then perform transition, but this isn't working.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div class="div"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transition: 2s;
}
.block {
  display:block;
}
.div-focused {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s;
}
.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

**jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inp").on("keyup", function () {
       if ( !$(this).val() ) {
           $(".div").removeClass("one");
       }
       else {
           $(".div").addClass("block");
           $(".div").addClass("div-focused");
           $(".div").addClass("one");
       }
    });
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrvuju0h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for an hack ? `Element.offsetTop` is your friend.

When you request this property, the browser is forced to make a reflow of the page, so the class are added and the transitions can trigger, synchronously.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".inp").on("keyup", function() {
    var $div = $('.div');
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      $div.removeClass("one");
    } else {
      $div.addClass("block");
      $div[0].offsetTop; // here is the magic
      $div.addClass("div-focused one");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transition: 2s;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

.div-focused {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s;
}

.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div class="div"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Could you please tell me, if you know of course: is this considered as performance heavy to reflow than use... `animate`, for example?

Comment: animate will change element's properties in an interval, so you'll get far more reflows and repaints than this single reflow. Also, browsers will reflow only if needed. So I'd say performance wise, better use this `offsetTop`

Comment: Thanks a lot once again! You're the best :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".inp").on("keyup", function () {
   if ( !$(this).val() ) {
       $(".div").removeClass("one");
   }
   else {
       $(".div").addClass("block");
         $(".div").addClass("one");
           $(".div").animate({opacity: "1"},500);
   }
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrvuju0h/1/)
Try This

Comment: Yes, I know about this approach, but I have doubts about it. Why isn't it working without timeout? The `.block` added before the transition.

Comment: display:none; removes a block from the page as if it were never there. A block cannot be partially displayed; it’s either there or it’s not. The same is true for visibility; you can’t expect a block to be half  hidden which, by definition, would be visible! Fortunately, you can use opacity for fading effects instead.

Comment: the `.block` is adding the `block` value to `display` before the `transition`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").hide();
    $(".inp").on("keyup", function () {
       if ( $(this).val()=="") {
           $("div").fadeOut(3000);
       } else {
        $("div").fadeIn(4000);
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: 2s;
}
.block {
  display:block;
}
.div-focused {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s;
}
.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly my code :) except of the additionally, but unnecessary functionality. This isn't working

Comment: Yes, I noticed. Thanks :) But this isn't related to the question... I'm looking for absolutely different functionality

Comment: which functionality you want?

Comment: I need the smooth transition effect on `display:none` element. I specifically used high value of `2` in `transition` so it will be noticeably  when it will work

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css and script with the below code.

```
/* style */
.div {
   display: none;
    height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: #000;
 }


/* Script */

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".inp").on("keyup", function () {
      if ( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(".div").css("opacity",0);
    }
    else {

       var item = $(this).val();
       var length = item.length;
       var opacity = length/10;
       $(".div").css("display","block");
       $(".div").css("opacity",opacity);
     }
   });
});
```

Try dis : https://jsfiddle.net/priyaraj/ggqztzvh/